# determine whether a ray collides with a triangle and distance to the collision point, in 3D

Tags: c++, 3d, raytracing

I'm looking for a method to determine whether a ray collides with triangle and distance to the collision point in 3D.

a method like the code below or something similar

```
float GetCollisionsoint(Vector3 RayPosition, Vector3 RayDirection, Vector3 a1, Vector3 a2, Vector3 a3)
    { 
    }
```

thanks in advance!

oh and if you now want to vote me down, please comment on why so I know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try looking at [GeometricTools](http://www.geometrictools.com/).

Comment: Do you know how to solve the 2D problem? That is, given a point and the vertices of a triangle, can you determine whether the point is inside the triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Sunday presents an [algorithm](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html) and a reference implementation. If the triangle's normal and `u`,`v` vectors are precomputed, the algorithm reduces to inner (dot) products. If the precomputed `u`,`v`,`n` are normalized, there are further optimizations: i.e., `<u,u> = <v,v> = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good write-up on the subject at http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/maths/ray-triangle-intersection/, along with some example code.